# Why this C# code is inserting data into wrong column of SQLite table?

Tags: c#, sqlite, microsoft.data.sqlite

**NOTE**: Many thanks to user `@David`. The issue has been resolved. That was my mistake. Please see the **UPDATE** section below.

**Environment**: [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli), VS2019 v16.6.0, Windows10 Pro v1903

**Question**: why is the following code inserting the value `"05-29-2020"` into the last column `DocContent`? I need it to insert `TestContent` instead. What I may be missing here and how can it be resolved?

**Remark**: On a button click `MyAddData()` calls `AddData()`

```
private void MyAddData()
{
    for (Int16 t=0; t<5; t++)
        MathDocsContext.AddData("Test" + t + "Author", "Test" + t + "Title", "Test Content");
}

public static void AddData(string sAuthor, string sTitle, string sDocContent)
{
    string SQLiteDbpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(GetDeployedFilePath, "SQLiteDb.db");

    using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection($"Filename={SQLiteDbpath}"))
    {
        db.Open();

        using (SqliteCommand insertCommand = new SqliteCommand())
        {
            insertCommand.Connection = db;

            // Use parameterized query to prevent SQL injection attacks
            insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Docs (Author, Title, DateModified, DocContent) VALUES (@Author, @Title, @DateModified, @DocContent);";
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", sAuthor);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", sTitle);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateModified", "05-29-2020");
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocContent", sDocContent);

            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        db.Close();
    }
}
```

SQLite table: data Inserted from above code

**Remark**: `DocId` is an auto-increment primary key identity column

**UPDATE**:

My apologies. I stand corrected. As user `@David` stated:

> Could be a variety of things outside the context of the code we're looking at.

The `Test Content` value in the `MyAddData()` method is not a value; instead a variable is passed here that has a value of `05-29-2020`.

[image]

Comment: Running an old version of the code?  Inserting into a different database instance than what you're observing?  Could be a variety of things outside the context of the code we're looking at.

Comment: @David I stand corrected. You were right in stating: `Could be a variety of things outside the context of the code we're looking at`. I have added a `NOTE` and an `UPDATE` section to my original post. Thank you for pointing out what could have been wrong.